# How can I use namespaces across files in C++?

Tags: c++

I have 2 .cpp files

a1.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

using namespace te;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    A a1(5);
    cout<<a1.display();
    return 0;
}
```

a2.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

namespace te
{
    class A{
        int i;
    public:
        A(int a)
        {i = a;}
        int display()
        {
            return i;
        }
    };
}
```

How do I use te in a1.cpp? Can I do it using header files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you require `a2.h`. Add `namespace te{ class A { public: A(int a); int display();};}` in the header file and include the header file from `a1.cpp`

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

#include "a2.cpp"

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    te::A a1(5);
    std::cout << a1.display() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This implies that `a2.cpp` is in the same folder as `a1.cpp`. It should be better though to make it a header file.

You should keep in mind that that it is generally to be avoided `using namespace XX;` and you should just have straight stuff. eg `std::cout`

It should be noted that `conio.h` is not part of standard `C` **edit:** and you are also using `cout` which is `C++`. You should try to avoid mixing the two Languages (Credits to DeadMG for clarification, see comment)

Comment: He's using cout. The important question is if it's part of Standard C++, not Standard C.

Comment: Sorry, but it's an awful advice to #include a .cpp file. Why suggesting a solution that works, but is generally unacceptable?

Comment: I mentioned that "it should be better though to make it a header file". I saw your answer as well, and I assumed OP will read all answers in this Question, so I thought no need to repeat answers.

Comment: for me in this case "should be" is simply not enough, personally I do not see any case when #include .cpp could be acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Just put Class A to header under namespace te and let a1 include it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your question is more about headers than namespaces: you already do use the namespace `te` in your a1.cpp (`using namespace te;`). The problem is the visibility of the class `te::A` for which you need to put its definition into a header and `#include` it. Without this, there is no way for the compiler to know that you have your class defined in a2.cpp when it compiles a1.cpp (each .cpp is compiled separately).

Comment: you seems to have written `#define` instead of `#include`. +1 anyway, the OP problem seems more about headers than namespaces.

Comment: yep, I've noticed and corrected this right after posting but apparently it is not instant for everyone.